# Firefox ignores width and height on the input type="image"

Tags: html, css, firefox

I create the image button. The button should change on hover. I set the image with CSS, so there is no need to use `src` attribute in my code. Chrome, Safari works well, but Firefox 48 completely ignores sizes of the input. I tried both CSS and HTML way. Is it a bug? What is the correct way?

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/nyppzpqx/5/

Here is the view in firefox 48:

[image: Firefox 48 OS X 10.10]

Comment: I've not looked at the spec but I would imagine that src is required for an image input. Otherwise you may as well just use a submit type.

Comment: ^ that's right. `"so there is no need to use src attribute in my code"`, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image makes it clear that "You must use the src attribute to define the source of the image"

Comment: Thank you.
I changed the input type to submit and removed the default styling with `border: none;`. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `display: block` to the `.btn-pay` element, it works just fine. It may be something with custom browser styles.

Altough as Turnip said, it is better to avoid using img element without src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can always restructure the way the html is written. This way you do not need the src attribute. The size is given to the outer div, and then the button is positioned on top of it with an image that spans the entire div:

```
<div class="btn-pay">
   <input type="button" name="kind" value="test" class="btn-pay-input" >
</div>
```

and then update the styling:

```
.btn-pay {
  width:135px;
  height: 60px;
}
.btn-pay-input {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/135x60);
  color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.btn-pay-input:hover {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/135x60/fff000);
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyppzpqx/8/)